# Holomorphically convex hull in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

It is known that every domain $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is homomorphically convex, i.e. $\hat{K}_{\Omega}$ is compact for all compact subset $K\subset \Omega$. However, is it true that $\hat{K}_{\Omega}=K$? If it is not true, when does it holds? Thanks in advance.

Edit : The definition of holomorphically convex hall is 
$$
\hat{K}_{\Omega} = \{x\in \Omega |\,\,|f(x)|\leq \max _{z\in K} |f(z)|\}.
$$

Comment: You should recall what is the meaning of notation $\hat{K}_{\Omega}$. The set of holomorphic functions such that ...

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not true that $\hat{K}_\Omega = K$ for $K \subset \Omega$ compact. Take for example $\Omega = \{ |z| < 1 \}$ and 
$$
K = \{ |z|=r \}
$$
for $0 < r < 1$. By the maximum modulus principle $\hat{K}_\Omega$ contains (and is in fact equal to) $\{ |z| \le r \}$.

Comment: If $K$ is simply connected, then $\hat{K}_{\Omega}=K$ is true?